# Oracle SQL - Update first substring

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the data in the column VPN like:

| ITEM | VPN |
| --- | --- |
| A124343 | 007-46-307-RED MEDIUM |
| A154363 | 008-25-203-YELLOW MEDIUM |

I have another table UPDATED_VPN as

| ITEM | VPN |
| --- | --- |
| A124343 | 024 |
| A154363 | 041 |

I want to update the first string of the VPN with the new VPN, matching the item
So

> A124343   007-46-307-RED MEDIUM

will become

> A124343   **024**-46-307-RED MEDIUM

how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement along with `EXISTS` within the `WHERE` condition
such as

```
UPDATE vpn v
   SET vpn = ( SELECT u.vpn||SUBSTR(v.vpn,INSTR(v.vpn,'-')) 
                 FROM updated_vpn u 
                WHERE u.item = v.item  )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM updated_vpn u WHERE u.item = v.item  )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VuitpePv)</kbd>

Alternatively using a `MERGE` statement with `MATCHED` option might also be used such as

```
MERGE INTO vpn v 
     USING updated_vpn u
        ON ( v.item = u.item )
      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET v.vpn = u.vpn||SUBSTR(v.vpn,INSTR(v.vpn,'-'))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PpY5JUxV)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
create table vpns (item varchar2(10), vpn varchar2(30));
create table updated_vpns (item varchar2(10), vpn varchar2(30));

insert all
    into vpns values ('A124343', '007-46-307-RED MEDIUM')
    into vpns values ('A154363', '008-25-203-YELLOW MEDIUM')
    into updated_vpns values ('A124343', '024')
    into updated_vpns values ('A154363', '041')
select * from dual;
```

Update statement (could also use merge):

```
update vpns v
set    v.vpn =
       ( select regexp_replace(v.vpn, '([^-]+)', u.vpn, 1, 2)
         from   updated_vpns u
         where  u.item = v.item );
```

Result:

```
ITEM       VPN
---------- ------------------------------
A124343    007-024-307-RED MEDIUM
A154363    008-041-203-YELLOW MEDIUM
```